Google Sheets API Reading the table
I don't know how to write code in order to read the information from the Sheet and send it to Winforms (VisualStudio) to get the values and output them to the user. also connected the Google.Apis.Sheets.v4 in NuGet. Info from GoogleForms Responses transmitted to GoogleSheets.
Google Console created a project in the google cloud Console, connected the Google Sheets API, created credentials.
json downolad the json Client secret.
All the code
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsSurvey
{
    public partial class Form6 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        public Form6()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {         
            var responseUrl = GoogleFormsService.ReadDataFromSheet("A1:B10");

            // Вывод URL в консоль
            Console.WriteLine("URL для просмотра ответов на форму:");
            Console.WriteLine(responseUrl);

            // Открытие URL в браузере
           // System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(responseUrl);
        }
    }

    public class GoogleFormsService
    {
        private static readonly string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets };
        private static readonly string ApplicationName = "Survey";
        private static readonly string SpreadsheetId = "1BO0Wa6TeNlqouYVN_RV0qjc4ucH-FdCOjhjI3oMaYLE";

        public static IList<IList<object>> ReadDataFromSheet(string range)
        {
            GoogleCredential credential;

            using (var stream = new FileStream(@"D:\PublishTest\client.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                    .CreateScoped(Scopes);
            }

            // Create Google Sheets API service.
            var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            // Define request parameters.
            SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest request =
                    service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(SpreadsheetId, range);

            // Make the request.
            ValueRange response = request.Execute();
            IList<IList<object>> values = response.Values;

            return values;
        }
    }
}


i dont know is it correct to connect this way, but in this code there is an error in the credential      = GoogleCredential line.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(Scopes);
System.InvalidOperationException: "Error creating credential from JSON or JSON parameters. Unrecognized credential type ."
